# jquery autocomplete submit issues in Mozilla

Tags: jquery, firefox, autocomplete, submit

I am implementing jquery autocomplete to show a list of products in a drop down and be able to search on it. In IE, when a user starts autofill and scrolls down to a suggestion and prett "Enter" key, it just select the item and focus remains on the search box.

In mozilla, when user scrolls down on auto fill and presses enter key, it performs a submit and search occurs automatically.

How can I stop that in Firefox?

Comment: Are you using an autocomplete plugin? If so, which one? If you're writing your own, please show or link to code.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick response. I am using a autocomplete plugin I inherited the project from someone, so might be a little off but the file points to this URL:

http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Is there any way I can attach the file to this question? Then you would have the whole file to reference?

Thanks,
nilaish

Comment: Can't reproduce. Doesn't submit for me on the demo page you linked to

Answer (score 2):

You may try to fix this by finding and editing a place in a plugin code which handles keypresses. That would look something like this:

```
someinput.keypress(function (event) {
var code = event.keyCode;
// handling of pressing the enter key
if (code == 13) {
    // preventing form submit
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

And let me advertise a bit my own multiselect plugin http://code.google.com/p/fpsfbmselect/